# How to move text upwards on the screen every time a button is pressed

Tags: kivy

I want to develop a chatting application for android. It will receive messages from the controller on the site. For this i have started designing a GUI. After practicing and studying a few codes I have been able to design a text box, a button and a label. When button is pressed, text in the text box gets displayed on the label named 'Display' and text box gets cleared. However now i want that with each time button is clicked text should move upwards and it's space should be replaced with the text in the text box. Similarly text from the sender should appear on the right side and text received should be displayed on left side of the screen. It might be a silly question but as i am totally new to python and kivy thing it is getting hard for me after trying it for over a week. Please guide me on this. Below is the code.
This is main.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

class scrollableLabel(FloatLayout):
    def display_txt(self):
        self.ids.lbl.text = self.ids.txt.text
        self.ids.txt.text = ''

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return scrollableLabel()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

This is the kivy file

```
<scrollableLabel>:
    FloatLayout:
    cols : 1
    rows : 3
    Button:
        text : 'Send'
        size_hint : .2 , .1
        pos : 640 , 0
        on_press : root.display_txt()

    TextInput:
        hint_text : 'Write here'
        id : txt
        size_hint : .8 , .1
        pos : 0 ,0

    Label :
        id : lbl
        text : 'Display'
        size_hint : .5 , .4
        pos : 500 , 100
        text_size : self.size
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Chat App - Suggestion

### [Kivy Label » Text alignment and wrapping](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#text-alignment-and-wrapping)

- Declare a custom widget with inheritance of `Label` widget so that you can control the text alignment i.e. left for text sent, and right for text received.

#### Snippets - kv file

```
<CustomLabel@Label>:
    size_hint_y: None
    text_size: self.width, None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    halign: 'left'
    valign: 'middle'
```

### [Kivy RecycleView](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html)

- Replace `Label:` with [`RecycleView:`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html)
- Use `CustomLabel` as the `viewclass`
- Append text sent or text received to RecycleView's `data`

#### Snippets - kv file

```
RecycleView:
    id: rv
    viewclass: 'CustomLabel'

    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

#### [Kivy RecycleView » data](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html#kivy.uix.recycleview.RecycleView.data)

> The view is generatad by processing the data, essentially a list of
>   dicts, and uses these dicts to generate instances of the viewclass as
>   required.
>
> ```
> data
> ```
>
> The data used by the current view adapter. This is a list of dicts
>   whose keys map to the corresponding property names of the
>   [viewclass](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html#kivy.uix.recycleview.RecycleView.viewclass).
>
> data is an [AliasProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.AliasProperty) that gets and sets the data used to
>   generate the views.

#### Snippets - Py file

```
    def display_txt(self):
        self.ids.rv.data.append({'text': self.ids.txt.text, 'halign': 'left'})
        self.ids.txt.text = ''
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


class SMS(Screen):
    def send_txt(self):
        self.ids.rv.data.append({'text': self.ids.txt.text, 'halign': 'left'})
        self.ids.txt.text = ''

    def receive_txt(self):
        self.ids.rv.data.append({'text': self.ids.txt.text, 'halign': 'right'})
        self.ids.txt.text = ''


Builder.load_file("main.kv")


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SMS()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

### main.kv

```
<ChatBox@Label>:
    size_hint_y: None
    text_size: self.width, None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    halign: 'left'
    valign: 'middle'

<SMS>:
    GridLayout:
        cols : 1

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            Button:
                text : 'Send'
                on_press : root.send_txt()
            Button:
                text : 'Receive'
                on_press : root.receive_txt()

        TextInput:
            hint_text : 'Write here'
            id : txt
            size_hint : .8 , .1
            pos : 0 ,0

        RecycleView:
            id: rv
            viewclass: 'ChatBox'

            RecycleBoxLayout:
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                orientation: 'vertical'
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: I am sorry for my lame understanding sir. I added 'Recycle View' and 'Custom Label@Label' directly to my kivy file.  But it didn't make any difference. When i typed the text in text input box and press the send button, text still appears and vanishes when next text is sent. It do not move upwards. How exactly do i have to use your suggestions. Again I am very sorry for my silly questions sir.

Comment: In method `display_txt()`, replace `self.ids.lbl.text = self.ids.txt.text` with `self.ids.rv.data.append({'text': self.ids.txt.text, 'halign': 'left'})`. Please refer to updated post for details.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. This is what I wanted. thank you once again for solving the difficulty.

Comment: Please remember to accept and/or up-vote the answer. Thank you.

Comment: hello sir, I tried to change the appearance a little bit. I wanted send, receive button and textinput at the bottom and label on top of it. And found that text starts to display from some height above the text input box and buttons. I need it to be displayed right above the buttons and text input box immediately. And in my code, text for both send and receive buttons are getting displayed on left hand side. Please tell me why it is so.

Comment: Replace the `GridLayout` with `BoxLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the appearance a little bit. I wanted send, receive button and textinput at the bottom and label on top of it. And found that text starts to display from some height above the text input box and buttons. I need it to be displayed right above the buttons and text input box immediately. And in my code, text for both send and receive buttons are getting displayed on left hand side. Please tell me why it is so.
Here is the .kv file
         :
              size_hint_x : None
              size_hint_y : None
              pos : 0,0
              text_size: self.width, None
              height: self.texture_size[1]
              halign: 'left'
              valign: 'middle'

```
     <CustomButton@Button>:
          font_size : 25
          size_hint : 0.1,0.1

     <MyWidget>:
          GridLayout:
              #size : root.width, root.height
              #orientation : 'horizontal'
              #pos:100,100
              cols:1
              row:3

              RecycleView:
                  id: rv
                  viewclass: 'ChatBox'

                  RecycleBoxLayout:
                      default_size_hint: 1, None
                      orientation: 'vertical'

              BoxLayout:
                  TextInput:
                      hint_text: 'type here'
                      id : txt
                      multiline : True
                      size_hint : .5,.1
                      #pos : 0,0
                  CustomButton:
                      text: 'Receive'
                      on_press : root.send_txt()
                      #pos : 10,0
                  CustomButton:
                      text: 'Send'
                      on_press : root.send_txt()
                      #pos : 20,0
```

Apart from that, when screen gets filled with the text and moved upwards completely, all the text disappears and if we again send or receives new text, it doesn't appear on the screen. Sir please tell me how to solve this issue.
Thanking you.